# Searching a string based on keywords (can't compare multiple keywords) VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, search, keyword

In my code I am adding a customer to a list if the keyword(s) are found within the string of Customer.Tags. Right now the customer is being added if one keyword is found. If I try to use more than one keyword it will use each keyword individually, i.e. search "bob" everyone with "bob" in tags will show up, great. But if you search "bob jordan" it will add every customer with "bob" in the tags as well as "jordan" in the tags but it will not ONLY show the customer with the first and last name of "bob jordan". How do I dynamically use an AND/OR statement to check every keyword against the customer.tags?

Basically I want IF Instr(customer.tags, wordsFound) searchedCustomerList.add(customer)

```
Function Search(searchKeyWords As List(Of String))
    Dim searchedCustomerList As New List(Of Customer)
    Dim foundWords As Boolean
    Dim wordsFound As New List(Of String)
    For Each customer In allCustomers
        For Each keyWord In searchKeyWords
            If InStr(customer.Tags, keyWord) > 0 Then
                'wordsFound does nothing right now, I need to make it so that multiple keywords (based on array/list size) are checked against Customer.Tags (AND or OR) before adding the customer to the list
                wordsFound.Add(keyWord)
                searchedCustomerList.Add(customer)
                foundWords = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If foundWords = True Then
        dgvCustomer.DataSource = searchedCustomerList
    ElseIf String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSearch.Text) Then
        GetAllCustomers()
    Else
        dgvCustomer.DataSource = Nothing
    End If
    txtSearch.Focus()
End Function

Private Sub TxtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    Dim keyWords As Array
    Dim keyWordTrimmedLower As String
    Dim searchKeyWords As New List(Of String)
    keyWordTrimmedLower = txtSearch.Text.TrimStart(" ").TrimEnd(" ").ToLower()
    keyWords = keyWordTrimmedLower.Split(" ")
    For Each keyWord In keyWords
        'If a keyword is just a blank space (found within each individual keyword) as the spaces before and after the search string are removed. This will make sure the empty space is not added to the search terms
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyWord) Then
            searchKeyWords.Add(keyWord)
        End If
    Next
    Search(searchKeyWords)
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps a space as the separator between keywords is not a good idea. Maybe customer.Tags would be better as a List(Of String).

Comment: @AndrewMorton So right now if we have customer.first = "bob" customer.last = "jordan" customer.email = "bobjordan@example.com" then customer.tags = bobjordanbobjordan@example.com. For me I want every keyword to be it's own string to see if it's located within customer.tags. I guess I just don't see how changing the long string of customer.tags to be a List(Of String) helps me compare multiple keywords to the String/List. Eventually it'd get to a point where it would be customer.tags.contains(key1 & key2 & key3) but I have no clue how to do the AND/OR operator, I can only compare 1 at a time.

Comment: So say if you don't remember the name of the client "Oh I know the first letter of his name and some of the phone number" If you search "b 318" this should be able to find "b" AND "318" in the customer.tags so only people with both show up instead of everyone with "b" and everyone with "318". I want this to be reversible as well, "318 b" should show up with the same results.

Comment: On the search form (or equivalent), could you have separate boxes for each field?